# DNN 2sxc | How to grant users permission to view all content items

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I have a custom 2sxc app, very much like a blog, that allows DNN users with edit-level permissions (default permissions) to add and update entities of a 2sxc content type called "Article". I would like users assigned the DNN "Content Editor" role to be able to access the "View all content items" dialogue for the "Article" content type, but by default they do not have permission to open the dialogue, even when forcing the toolbar button to display to these users.

["View all content items" dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrfNf.png)

[2sxc toolbar buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFVuR.png)

I tried using 2sxc's [Permissions](https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/cms/permissions/index.html) feature to solve the issue. First, I tried giving users with Edit-level access Full Control over the "Article" content type. When this didn't work, I tried targeting users with View-level access. This didn't work either. Finally, I tried adding the same permission configurations (edit/view -level and Full Control) to the app permissions, but this also did not work.

[2sxc permissions dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMAhF.png)

Am I doing something wrong here? Is it even possible to give Content Editor users permission to view the "View all content items" dialogue?

Comment: as of now I believe the permissions you would end up giving result in admin-permissions on the app. If you really need just this, you will need to open an issue and describe the use case in detail.